# Why are my buttons/links not aligned in the center?

Tags: html, css

CodePen: http://codepen.io/hgducharme/pen/juiEo

My links on the right side are not in the middle of the `ul` box. The avatar on the far right is positioned at the very top, and if I want to change the margin-top of my `li` elements, then it basis it off of the top of my avatar. I have `margin-top: 0px;`, which moves all my `li` elements to the top, but my avatar is staggered. I want to be able to get them all in a straight even line.

I'm currently trying to rebuild google's homepage.

Edit: Browser is Chrome

Comment: What @Jean-FrançoisSavard said, also consider removing the default `padding` which is applied by UAs to list elements such as `<ul>` by `padding: 0;`

Comment: @Hunter, When asking questions about web design, please specify your browser as it may differ a lot between IE9 and Chrome for example. If you do so, it will be easier for me to explain the reason of this behavior instead of simply throwing a solution as Hashem commented on my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the vertical align :

```
li {
     vertical-align:middle;
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
     padding: 5px;
     border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: While true, it doesn't explain the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. One more question: On the '<li class="share">', I can get my text to align in the center of the box (horizontally), but not in the center of the box (vertically). I added a 'line-spacing: 28px;' which did the trick, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Because inline and inline block with a known height, in this case 60px needs the vertical-alignment. Common CSS knowledge. Knowing what is inline, what is block, what is inline-block and how floats work is base knowledge.

Comment: Christina is right, except that the height in that case is 30px, 60 is the width ;)

Comment: On the #share use line-height equal to the height of the container.   line-height:30px;

Comment: Parent of the li is 60px (#nav), the li itself is not set, the padding, text, line-height makes the height.

Comment: @Christina So inline & inline-block just knew that it needed to be placed horizontally in the ul container (or the nav container)? But it didn't know what height to put it at, so the height must be specified (as middle, in this case) to position them accordingly?

Comment: inline-block elements and inline when the height of the parent is set and you put a vertical-align:middle css works this way.

Comment: Horizontal alignment is different. Inline is just all inline. Spans are inline, em, and so forth. You can also change a block to inline.

Comment: Actually, they're not lined up because as inline level elements they are sitting in their baseline. The baseline of inline-block elements is defined in the spec. By using `vertical-align` property, you'll alter their position.

Comment: Yes, this is basic knowledge. This stuff should be known before SO